# Centering a linearlayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, dynamic, position, center

I have the following code which dynamically creates clickable ImageViews, (depending on what value you can make it 2x2 3x3 4x4 etc...)
Everything is working fine except I want the imageViews to be centered, right now they start at the left of the screen. I want the whole collection of imageviews to be in the center of the screen.

```
 private void maakLayout() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    setContentView(linearLayout);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (2) * 10);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutTextParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutTextParams.topMargin = 50;
    layoutTextParams.bottomMargin = 50;
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutTextParams);

    textViewScore = textView;
    linearLayout.addView(textView);


    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < RASTER; i++) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        //linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layoutParams1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutImageParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutImageParams);
        linearLayout.addView(linearLayout1);

        for (int j = 0; j < RASTER; j++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
            imageView.setTag(k);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_gray);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutImageParams1 =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
            layoutImageParams.topMargin = 2;
            layoutImageParams.leftMargin = 2;
            layoutImageParams1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutImageParams1);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    klikopknop((ImageView) v);
                }
            });

            knoppen[k] = imageView;
            linearLayout1.addView(imageView);
            k++;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ImageView's width LayoutParams to `MATCH_PARENT` and the scaleType to `CENTER_INSIDE`

Answer (score 0):

Use Realtive layout and put your imageview in Relative layout. Then add rule, RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT.